# Run Bash Script File from JAVA

Tags: java, bash, function, postgresql, shell

I work with Bash script. My bash script is

```
#!/bin/bash


function aa(){
   echo "Run";
   su - postgres -c "shp2pgsql -I -s 4269  /tmp/gismanager/Wards.shp ff | psql  postgis;";
   echo "Run";
   return 0;
}

aa;
```

when this script run by linux result is `Run Run` but from java result is `Run`

my java code is

```
public static void execShellCmd(String path) {
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runtime.exec(path);
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("exec response: " + line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try looking at these links to other bash/Java issues

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791251/running-bash-script-from-java
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711308/how-can-i-run-a-bash-script-which-downloads-a-file-in-java
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955509/running-bash-script-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to capture the OutputStream and ErrorStream?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
InputStream errorStream = process.getErrorStream();

BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorStream));
```